# how to use lpad in mysql query if the length is 11

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Please find my table structure:

TabA

col1
018
28
19
9

Now I need to write a query which will populate the data in the following manner

018
028
019
009

Means the logic is if the length of col1 is 1 digit then LPAD 00 and if the length is 2 then LPAD 0

If the length is 3 then we will not add anything

I am really struggling with this situation, any help is appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

after wrecking my head got the solution here

SELECT DISTINCT LPAD(col1, 13, 0) AS col1 FROM tabA